# Input list of numbers into sum formula MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a long list of characterstics like this:

```
{freq: 0, amp: 1154.6588660054892, phase: 0.6811527708352859}
{freq: 1, amp: 233.76302050080815, phase: -2.277730816435749}
{freq: 2, amp: 143.2507105748049, phase: -1.6688604056674772}
{freq: 3, amp: 61.34267912110249, phase: -1.407276624718863}
{freq: 4, amp: 69.82165621191676, phase: 0.4484639726070131}
{freq: 5, amp: 124.7089820392834, phase: -2.69715415885439}
{freq: 6, amp: 98.10782045873147, phase: -2.257663813503815}
{freq: 7, amp: 45.692851840698864, phase: 2.0834837932685986}
{freq: 8, amp: 13.755486310098496, phase: -0.9882950412130524}
{freq: 9, amp: 37.04634258561415, phase: 1.0277190546903878}
{freq: 10, amp: 57.320618660063865, phase: 0.9419518346957391}
{freq: 11, amp: 5.566488239052793, phase: -1.1325389453638341}
{freq: 12, amp: 4.611944397255416, phase: 0.14233997398390724}
{freq: 13, amp: 66.65783488521923, phase: -1.592500420430998}
{freq: 14, amp: 28.96466186646502, phase: 2.507516417595699}
{freq: 15, amp: 49.2744858240047, phase: 2.7774600258970668}
{freq: 16, amp: 10.210149563013712, phase: -0.978331488766217}
{freq: 17, amp: 16.59276204808539, phase: -2.4968547381563684}
...
```

in an excel file. Each of these numbers describes a part of Cn in the equation below:

[image]

Cn is a Complex Number and is represented like this:

```
[amp]*e^(pi*i*[phase])
```

where [Freq] is n in the formula

hence the list of numbers go into this Cn.

This Video From 3D1B describes the concepts discussed here in great detail in an easy to follow way. (14min - 24min)

How can i compute Sn(x). So it would be

```
C0*e^[i*pi*((0))*x]/P + C1*e^[i*pi*((1))*x]/P + C2*e^[i*pi*((2))*x]/P
```

=
in my case using the data above:

```
[1154]*e^(pi*i*[0.68])*e^[i*pi*((0))*x]/P + [233]*e^(pi*i*[-2.27])*e^[i*pi*((1))*x]/P + [143]*e^(pi*i*[1.66])*e^[i*pi*((2))*x]/P....... until my data is done
```

> GOAL: How can i do this in matlab --> Solve Complete Sum

[image]

Comment: What exactly is your problem? The data you show (`{freq: 0 ...}`) is no valid MATLAB. Thus, is your question how to convert this data (maybe from a file) to MATLAB, or, given you have your data in valid MATLAB, how to compute `Sn(x)`? In the latter case we need to know how the data is stored in MATLAB.

Comment: I just added the labels to make it clear. It is a 3xN in excel. 3 columns and N rows. I can put it in matlab no problem. Say p = [amp, freq, phase] but how do I compute Sn. Sn uses all this data.

Answer (score 1):

I reduce the data to your first three data points

```
amp = [1154.6588660054892, 233.76302050080815, 143.2507105748049];
phase = [0.6811527708352859, -2.277730816435749, -1.6688604056674772];
```

You can compute cn like this

```
cn = amp .* exp(pi* 1j * phase);
```

This is just a vector of your `freq` for three data points:

```
n = 0:numel(amp)-1;
```

To compute `Sn(x)`, I need `x` and `P` (shouldn't it be `S_n(x,P)`?) [**Update** Use a vector for `x`]:

```
x = 0:.5:30;
P = 18;
```

and `Sn(x)` could be simply computed in a loop:

```
Sn = zeros(size(x));
for idx = 1:numel(x)
    Sn(idx) = sum(cn.*exp(1j*pi.*n*x(idx)/P));
end
```

Plot `Sn`:

```
plot3(real(Sn), imag(Sn), x);

xlabel("real(S_n)");
ylabel("imag(S_n)");
zlabel("time");
```

[image]

Comment: And then how do I change the value of x. (Time) and watch the point move, tracing its path

Comment: See my edit. If you want to make a movie of it, try it yourself. If you get stuck, ask another question.

Comment: i get this error with your code. Unable to perform assignment because the left and right sides have a different number of elements. on the Sn(idx) = sum...

Comment: how did you get that graph? i get a straight line upwards

Comment: I don't get an error and I receive this plot (I might have rotated it a bit). Check the code and close all figures before running it.

Comment: i updated my question. Take a look at the picture. I got the graph you have using the 3 data you used, but when i add more it doesnt work. Also the sum on wikipedia says it goes from -n to n.

Comment: Maybe. I have tried all the values you provided in your question, and I get a (very nice looking) curve. BTW: You should add some explanation to the image in your question, otherwise future readers will not understand it.

Comment: Could you quickly shared that image

Comment: Ok thanks. I’ll give it a shot with even more data now

Comment: How do you determine p and the range for x?

Comment: Since you did not provide any information about `P`, I choose an arbitrary value. After looking at some combinations of `P` and `x` it seemed to me that the curve repeats after `2*P`, thus I chose `x=0:.05:2*P`. I have not proven this, but it is your function and you should know by far more about it than me, and for sure this is far beyond a MATLAB related topic.

Comment: P is values.lenght. So if you have 45 Val’s, p is 45

Comment: Changing `P` without changing the number of data in `amp` and `phase` just scales the curve along `x`.